# h2o Flow UI not working

Tags: python-2.7, h2o

I recently upgraded to H2O-3.11.0.3820. My web based flow ui is not working. 
When I go to the link, i get a light blue colored screen with all the options that I used to get earlier, missing.

Unable to find anything relevant on stackoverflow. Any one else facing similar issue? Any help will be much appreciated!

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321..... not found.
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.17.0.3-win64) (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
Starting server from C:\Users\shekh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\bin\h2o.jar
Ice root: c:\users\shekh\appdata\local\temp\tmpvrxqvd
JVM stdout: c:\users\shekh\appdata\local\temp\tmpvrxqvd\h2o_shekh_started_from_python.out
JVM stderr: c:\users\shekh\appdata\local\temp\tmpvrxqvd\h2o_shekh_started_from_python.err
Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:54321
Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:54321... successful.
--------------------------  ------------------------------
H2O cluster uptime:         03 secs
H2O cluster version:        3.11.0.3820
H2O cluster version age:    5 days
H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_shekh_vdbwfl
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    51.56 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    0
H2O cluster allowed cores:  0
H2O cluster status:         accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url:         http://127.0.0.1:54321
H2O connection proxy:
H2O internal security:      False
Python version:             2.7.12 final
--------------------------  ------------------------------
```

Comment: hi spartacus, can you share a screenshot of what you seen in the browser when you visit  http://127.0.0.1:54321 ?

Comment: Hi Micah! Thanks for reaching out. I could have waited, I realized that I had mistakenly installed the latest version, and not the stable release. Once I did that, things are working fine.

Comment: glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, install a stable release of H2O-3.

Nightly builds are number 3.ODD.y.z

Stable builds are numbered 3.EVEN.y.z

(So 3.11.0.3820 is a random bleeding edge build, not a stable build.)